# How to have an index by multiple proximity effectors, to affect different affected areas as islands?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this simple setup that takes a collection of effectors and scales parts of a sphere by proximity.
Let's say I want to make each affected area have a different scale, it seems that when I add a random node it randomizes every single vertex and not by affected area as a whole. Is there a way to do that?
[image]